# How can I dynamically set an id within a Javascript loop?

Tags: javascript, flot

I have a list of Questions, and each of those Questions has a list of Answers (which can be any integer from 1-5).  I would like to dynamically create a chart for each Question, using the count of all answers that match a specific "rank"; i.e. all the answers that were a '1', '2', '3', etc.

So what I've done is set a for loop that creates an element for each question; this element is used as a placeholder for the chart.  (As an aside, I am using flot charts).

The problem I'm having is trying to name the placeholders dynamically; what I really want is to create something that ends up looking like this:

```
<div id='chart1'/>
<div id='chart2'/>
```

etc

The closest I've managed is this:

```
<div id="'chart'@currentQuestion"/>
```

which of course gives an id like this: 'chart'1

Later, when I try to append the chart to the div I've created, the following doesn't work:

```
$("#'chart'"+i).append(div); //where i is the current loop counter
```

If I use

```
 $("#chart"+i).append(div);
```

it correctly finds the element 'chart1', 'chart2' etc; but I'm struggling to name the div to match.

Can anyone help?  It seems trivial unless you know how to solve it :-)

Edit: As requested, here is the relevant HMTL:

```
<div id="'chart@currentQuestion'">CHART</div>
```

SOLVED:

Like this: id="chart@(currentQuestion)" (via a colleague) Thanks for your efforts.

Comment: can you show us the loop you're using to generate the charts to begin with?

Comment: Please do not self close divs.

Comment: Perhaps all you need is this: `<div id="'chart@currentQuestion'"></div>
`?

Comment: @Asad: no, that is what I've already tried.  It just gives me something like "'chart'1"

Comment: Could you please post the full js you are using to generate the charts? In particular, I do not understand how 'chart@currentQuestion' is being replaced by 'chart1'.

Comment: Sorry, @currentQuestion is a counter within the loop, with an integer value. Anyway, I've found a solution, like this:  id="chart@(currentQuestion)"  Thanks for the help!

Comment: this question is about usage of razor syntax with javacript. not just javascript.

Comment: @BerkerYüceer maybe, sorry for lack of knowledge/understanding

Answer (score 0):

You haveen't close your div correctly. try this code

```
<div id='chart1' style="border:dashed">
</div>
<br />

<div id='chart2' style="border:dotted">
</div>

<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery_library.js">
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
 function fnc(value){

$("#chart"+value).append('1');
}
</script>
<input type="button" onclick="fnc(1)" value="for div1"/>
<input type="button" onclick="fnc(2)"value="for div2" />
```

Comment: Sorry but this doesn't answer my problem.  I need to be able to create the ids dynamically based on Javascript; here you have hardcoded the values of id

Comment: You think that we will just simply provide you the whole code so that you can copy and paste the code. That's not true. This was just and idea of dynamically creating ids. You can use it to append divs.

Comment: Well thank you for your idea, but it still doesn't solve the question.  I already know how to do what you have proposed.  I am interested in learning to solve problems, not just copy pasting.  Sorry you feel that way.

Comment: +1 polin's code just works perfectly and relative to questions title.

Comment: Thanks Berker. I also thought so.

Answer (score 0):

You are using razor syntax, so here how it should be.

```
// Define your counter
@{long i = 0;}

// On document ready dynamically add your items
$("document").ready(function(){
    // Create red divs starting by zero
    // after 5 divs stop creating red divs
    @for (i = 0;i<5;i++){
        @:$("#form").append('<div id="chart' + @(i) + '">Red</div>');
    }
});

// I made a button for action, you can choose other ways to invoke this function
$("#form>input").click(function(){
    // Your counter is at 4 now
    // lets change it to 2 
    @(i = 2;) // Now your counter is at 2 
    // Put a blue div into 2nd div starting by 0
    $("#chart"+@(i)).append('<div class="blue">blue</div>');
});
```

this is how you use razor syntax with scripts

Comment: This doesn't answer the question.  I need to be able to control where the objects are placed, hence I am trying to use this method: <div id="'chart'@currentQuestion"/>, rather than using code to create the objects and add them to the page.  After all, I need to know where the objects should be placed, which - if I use your solution - will require me to dynamically allocate ids to placeholders... leaving me in the same situation I'm in now :-)

Comment: is @currentQuestion a counter?

Comment: yes.  I have actually just been handed a solution by a colleague, using a bracket around the variable like this: id="chart@(currentQuestion)"  Thanks for your help.